# MobaXterm update no longer copies and pastes without adding line breaks

Tags: copy-paste, vi, line-breaks, cat, mobaxterm

I recently migrated mac to catalina which forced me to update vmware fusion which then forced me to upgrade mobaXterm to 12.4.

After the mobaXterm update, when I copy a single wrapped line from vi or via cat in a terminal, mobaXterm pastes a line break rather than respecting the line wrap.

This was not an issue with whatever old version (11.x) I was running previously and I can't find anything helpful on the google.

Anyone know how to fix / why this is happening?  I'm running the 'linux' TERM type on rhel.